# How to exclude current post info from user_meta foreach loop in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a simple "Favorite Posts" button that logged in users can click to save a post to their list of "Favorites." The button appends the current post ID to a user_meta field.

I'm a bit stuck when it comes to displaying the info on a "My Favorites" page, however.

I can display a list of favorite post IDs without issue, but when I try to add information like post titles and permalinks, Wordpress passes on the "My Favorites" page information into the array. Above the list of "Favorites," users will also see a hyperlinked "My Favorites".

Any thoughts on how to prevent this from happening. Here's the code...

```
<?php //start favorites list
    // Get user info.
    global $current_user, $wp_roles;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $myFaves = get_user_meta($current_user->id, 'faveposts', true);
    $myFavesArray = explode(',',$myFaves);
    sort($myFavesArray);

    foreach ($myFavesArray as $myFave) :
?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $myFave ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_title($myFave); ?>
    </a>

<?php endforeach; //end favorites list ?>
```

And here's the output...

```
<a href="http://sample-url.com/favorites/">
    Your Favorites
</a>

<a href="http://sample-url.com/post-1/">
    Post Title 1
</a>

<a href="http://sample-url.com/post-2/">
    Post Title 2
</a>
```

Post Title 1 and 2 are examples of actual favorited posts. Your Favorites is the page displaying favorites (that shouldn't be showing up).

Thoughts?

**EDIT**

Found a fix. Adding this bit of code removed the current post from the array...

```
unset($myFavesArray[0]);
```

So the final code is...

```
$myFaves = get_user_meta($current_user->id, 'faveposts', true);
$myFavesArray = explode(',',$myFaves);
unset($myFavesArray[0]);
sort($myFavesArray);

foreach ($myFavesArray as $myFave) :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your code, it's seems $myFavesArray's first index value is empty.
so that when you use [get_permalink()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) due to passing first time empty parameter it's return current post link. so you need to unset $myFavesArray[0] first index of array.

One suggestion:
when you save value in user meta, do code for remove empty value in array and store unique values in array. after that you don't need to do any operation on user_meta when you retrieve.

Hope this helps you. All the best ;)

Comment: Thanks @techguy4web! As you probably picked up, I'm new to working with php and arrays, so sometimes obvious stuff like this slips right past me. Cheers!